# making sql query dynamic based on slicer date

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am a new user of power bi and i wanted to know two things.

1. Is it possible to get data from mysql datasouce in real time based on query.
2. how to dynamically change the mysql query parameter based on slicer. e.g. if i have a query

**select * from table name where date = 10/12/2019**

than i want to change the date dynamically based on slicer visual
say in my slicer i have dates of different months and I select 12/01/2020 from slicer than the above query should act based on 12/01/2020 i.e **select * from table name where date = 12/01/2020**
How can i achieve this in power bi?

Comment: Power BI will do that for you. Change your query to `select * from table name` only and add a slicer for `date` field.

Comment: Actually my scenerio is very complex and i have to follow the requriement defined above. I wrote the above query simple so that reader can understand my requirement.

Comment: Then your simple example has nothing in common with the real complex requirement. To get any meaningful assistance, you should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then update your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called Direct Query, but that's not supported for MySQL data sources. ([Datasource supported feature list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources))

You might be able to do some tricks on PowerBI Desktop using [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-templates#:%7E:text=With%20Power%20BI%20Desktop%20templates,%2C%20data%20model%2C%20and%20queries.) and ask for parameters first, then run a query. But that's not the proper usage of the functionality and you won't be able to use it anyway in the PowerBI Service (since you can't deploy a template). This also tends to be tricky and requires a good amount of manual work in M language (Power Query)

Summarizing, for your case I think the answer is no.